# SQL: What different between conditions using "all" and "min" in this query?

Tags: sql

What different?

RIGHT:

```
select distinct maker, price from product
inner join printer
on product.model = printer.model
where color = 'y' and price <= (select min(price) from printer where color = 'y')
```

WRONG:

```
select distinct maker, price from product
inner join printer
on product.model = printer.model
where color = 'y' and price <= all (select distinct price from printer where color = 'y')
```

I know using "min" is better in performance.
But could anyone explain what wrong and different in the result?

Tables structures:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

neikel

Comment: Why would you say the second query is wrong? Does it return incorrect results? Or does it not conform to someones standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALL** is a short form for expanding the comparison operator against ALL rows, and combining the conditions with AND.
**ANY** is a short form for expanding the comparison operator against ALL rows, and combining the conditions with OR.

Specifically,

```
price <= all (select distinct price from printer where color = 'y')
```

expands to, assuming the subquery returns 4 rows

```
price <= <price1> AND
price <= <price2> AND
price <= <price3> AND
price <= <price4>
```

When any of those resove to NULL, the result is **false** because NULL is not comparable using `<=`.  MIN doesn't have this problem (because MIN skips NULLs) except for the edge case where there is NO result row, in which case `<= (select MIN..)` can also give you an unexpected result.

Using ALL in to perform a test against a nullable column should *almost always* be qualified with a filter, e.g.

```
select distinct maker, price from product
inner join printer
on product.model = printer.model
where color = 'y' and price <=
      all (select distinct price from printer where color = 'y'
           where price is not null)
```

Comment: Comparing `NULL` with `<=` does not give `FALSE`; it gives `UNKNOWN`. `(NULL <= 2) = FALSE` is not true.

Comment: @Billy, it returns `FALSE` in the context of the condition, i.e. it will not proceed, which requires a true. You yourself say in another comment that it `coerces to FALSE`, so if we're still discussing in the same frame of reference (return from the condition), it's as false as false can be.

Comment: For the purposes of the while, yes; because where checks for true, and null is not true. But being inside the where does not change the behavior of the condition. (42 <= null) = false is still null, despite being in the where; but the way you have the above worded would lead someone to believe the reverse. Particularly when confusion around SQL's 3 valued logic is what led to the confusion in the first place, being explicit about what is actually occurring is valid.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: you are right, I checked that on MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

The second one will fail if there is a NULL `printers.price`. Consider this (I'm using PostgreSQL here):

```
=> select 0 <= (select min(x) from (values (null), (1), (2)) as t(x));
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

and this:

```
=> select 0 <= all (select x from (values (null), (1), (2)) as t(x));
 ?column? 
----------

(1 row)
```

That's a true result in the first case and NULL (which is false) for the second one.

Comment: Technically ANSI rules would have comparison against `NULL` return `UNKNOWN` (which the `where` clause coerces to false). +1

Comment: @BillyONeal: Are there any databases with an explicit UNKNOWN? Everything I've worked with uses NULL for that.

Comment: I don't think there'd be a functional difference between the two. The docs for MSSQL say that it returns an explicit `UNKNOWN` if ANSI NULLS is turned on; but I have not tested myself; so `UNKNOWN` might just be the docs' word for `NULL`.

Comment: C.J. Date's comment on the standard keeps coming to mind, paraphrasing: "don't blame for NULL! I don't like it either!"

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>ALL is a Transact-SQL extension; it is not supported by all database engines.</s> Oops.
2. Performance is not negligible when talking about databases. The `min` solution can probably use an index to execute extremely quickly (assuming the RDBMS builds a B-tree or similar sorted index), whereas the all solution forces a full table scan.
3. If `price` is allowed to be null, you will get different answers. `min` ignores all null values, so if `price` is null, the result of the min will be a number. But the result of your distinct query will attempt to compare that null against all the prices, which will return `UNKNOWN` for every price, which means no prices will match in the `where` clause.

Comment: If there is an index to use for **MIN**, would it not be able to use that exact same index for distinct? I do aggree with the multiple comparisons though.

Comment: @astander: The database can use the index for the `distinct`, but it cannot use the index for the `all`. (After all, `all` means compare against every result)